# How to publish tables from SQL database as datasets automatically into CKAN

Tags: ckan

I am implementing open data portal for uni students such that they have access to all the datasets generated in different buildings of uni and they can work on the data to develop interesting applications.

I have installed CKAN. Its working fine. I have implemented harvester as well.

My main concern is :
University has system that is storing the data coming from different sensors like temperature, light, noise etc. 
The aim of project is to connect the data stored on system to the ckan so that data is synced between data stored on systems and open data platform. I tried harvesting for few source types.

Can you please guide me what is the best feature that can help me connect to University data storage system.

Do uni need to set up the web server from with whcih we can connect the CKAN by CKAN harvesting?

Do we need to implement a new extension like publicopendataeu uses(eg. opengov_se etc.) to connect to different resources or we can use the existing extensions ?

What format you recommend the uni to store their data in?
Currently the data is stored as SQL database.

is there any way we can connect those SQL tables to Ckan and import those tables as datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Try [this CKAN extension](https://github.com/cphsolutionslab/ckanext-dataproxy). The idea is to allow viewing of remote SQL tables. The last time I tried it I didn't succeed but it looks like it was updated very recently and claims CKAN 2.5 compatibility.
- Use the [Datastore and Datastore API](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#the-datastore-api) to have the underlying sensors/datasource write to CKAN directly
- Have the current system write to CKAN Datastore tables directly (i.e. ignore the API). Not so nice but perhaps less work if you already have everything set up for DB writes. You would need to create the initial CKAN datasets and resources (1 SQL table per resource) first
- (Similar to above) Create some elegant mirroring/replication system between the database tables. Maybe only possible/straightforward if both DBs are Postgres.
- Harvesting would work, but you would have to write your own harvester that queries/performs an export from the database and imports/updates it into CKAN resources
- (Similar to above) Independent script that queries/performs an export from the database and imports/updates it into CKAN resources using the CKAN/CKAN Datastore API

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very helpful. I synched the two databases and as the change is reflected in table in ckan database the associated table gets refreshed.

Comment: That would be worth a blog post at CKAN.org!

Comment: @TanyaArora I wonder how you achieved the sync? Is there a trigger in table in CKAN database that can be used to write to the associated table remotely?